# PHP MySql комменты

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

fr7903p5.bget.ru/about.php - сайт (комменты в конце)

Чтение:

```
<?php
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', ' ', ' ')or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");

if (!$mysql)
{
echo("БД Не доступна!");
exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($mysql, 'fr7903p5_arduino');

mysqli_set_charset($mysql, "utf8");
$sql = "SELECT message FROM `messages`";
$sql1 = "SELECT author FROM `messages`";

$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql1);

$d = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$d1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

$count = 0;

if($result) {
foreach($d as $row)
{
echo 'Автор:'.$d1[$count];
print(''.
'');
echo 'Комментарий:'.$row;
echo(''.

'');
$count += 1;
}
}
else {
echo 'mysqli_query вернул пустую строку.';
echo mysqli_error($mysql);
}

mysqli_close($mysql);
?>
```

Запись:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$coment = $_POST["coment"];
$date = date("m.d.y");
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', ' ', ' ')or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");

if (!$mysql)
{
echo("БД Не доступна!");
exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($mysql, 'fr7903p5_arduino');

mysqli_set_charset($mysql, "utf8");
$sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`author`, `message`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$coment', '$date')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
mysqli_fetch_array($result);

mysqli_close($mysql);
include('about.php');
?>
```

Пишу комменты на php + mysql. Коменты выводятся всего 2 раза + они повтаряются. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а по какому учебнику вы учитесь?

Comment: Инет, учебника нет

Comment: ну неважно. в инете тоже какие-то материалы. там наверняка есть пример выборки из БД. почему бы не сделать точно как в примере?

Comment: `foreach()` перебирает без всяких дополнительных `$count`, обращаться надо `$row['message']` и $row['author'], но вообще выборку данных делай одним запросом, к примеру `SELECT author, message FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10`